# Google sheets equipment borrowing system

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on this Google Sheets system where it shows who has what item. I have never worked with Google Apps Script before, but basically what I want it to do is to check the value of C2, then make the sheet copy some of the data (D2, E2, G2) from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5zIR.png) (it will always be trying to copy the 2nd column) and move it [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH4n8.png) (in a different sheet but the same document) next to the corresponding name on each particular section

Comment: Be more objective, it's not important if you ever done JS before. You can embed the image in the post, check the editor functionalities. I had to read some times to figure out what you want. Make your question more clear to get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is rotate the data so columns becomes rows, and rows become columns, right?

What you need is `[transpose][1]` function.

For example, in A2, if you put `=transpose('Sheet 2'!C1:1)`, Google Sheets will automatically fill the A column with values of first row of 'Sheet 2', starting at C1 position.

UPDATED ANSWER:

Here is the [working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10WfgTiHS5SIcfZImNL97Bwnf0yk4NcUl1X91GRw-8MA/edit#gid=896320467)

Here are the steps:

1. Get a filtered list of all timestamp with matched equipment
2. Sort the list so it's reverse order
3. Get the first item from the sorted list ("last date")
4. Get the position of "last date" in the timestamp list
5. Get the item in the action list at the same position as "last date"
6. If the item is "Check out" then it's not available.
7. Note: you might want to store the result of `index()` in a hidden cell

Comment: That doesn't work as it will always be new results in the top row and I want if sheet1 C2 = 1.1 macbook 1 then copy (sheet 1)D2, E2, G2 to (sheet 2)C2,C3,C4 but if Sheet1 C2 = 1.1 macbook 2 then copy (sheet1) D2, E2, G2 to (Sheet 2 ) C7,C8,C9

Comment: Answer updated. Can you please edit the title of you question so it is more search friendly?